# Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404'}

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to use `axios.get()` to check if a user exists in the database, however I get the 404 error in my console when I  click the button that that runs the axios code.
[image]

My frontend code:

```
  const handlecreateChannel = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log("rival: ", rivalUsername);
    console.log(`${allUsersRoute}/${rivalUsername}`)
    const response = await axios.get(`${allUsersRoute}/${rivalUsername}`);
    console.log("does rival exist ", response.data.isExist);
  };

return(
   <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Username of rival..."
        value={rivalUsername}
        onChange={(event) => setRivalUsername(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handlecreateChannel}>Join/Start game</button>
</div>
)
```

^ console.log output reflects the correct `rivalUsername` and correct axios path.

I have included the path in my server userRoutes.js:
`router.post("/allusers/:username", getRival)`

userRoutes.js calls my `getRival` function in userController:

```
module.exports.getRival = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        user = req.params.username
        const isExist = await User.findOne({ user })
        if (!isExist){
            return res.json({status: false})
        }
        return res.json(isExist)
    }catch(e){
        next(e)
    }
}
```

Can someone advice on the axios 404 error, I think my code makes sense... Thank you I really appreciate it

Comment: Could be that you are doing a get request on a post endpoint?

Comment: also, should it be findOne({ user:"user" })

Answer (score 0):

Use `router.get` instead of `router.post` in [your code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woxp0.png).

Frontend and backend methods should be the same.